# How does rolling update work in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How does rolling update work in kubernetes internally. Is it one pod after another. will the update get stuck or takes time if one of the pod goes to error state during the update

Answer (score 0):

From [design document](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/cli/simple-rolling-update.md):

> For the purposes of this example, assume that we are rolling from `foo` to `foo-next` where the only change is an image update from `v1` to `v2`
>
> If the user doesn't specify a `foo-nex`t name, then it is either discovered from the update-partner annotation on foo. If that annotation doesn't exist, then foo-next is synthesized using the pattern `<controller-name>-<hash-of-next-controller-JSON>`
>
> **Initialization**
>
> - If `foo` and `foo-next` do not exist:
>
>   - Exit, and indicate an error to the user, that the specified controller doesn't exist.
> - If `foo` exists, but `foo-next` does not:
>
>   - Create `foo-next` populate it with the `v2` image, set `desired-replicas` to `foo.Spec.Replicas`
> - If `foo-next` exists, but `foo` does not:
>
>   - Assume that we are in the rename phase.
>   - Goto Rename
> - If both `foo` and `foo-next` exist:
>
>   - Assume that we are in a partial rollout
>   - If `foo-next` is missing the `desired-replicas` annotation
>
>     - Populate the `desired-replicas` annotation to `foo-next` using the current size of `foo`
> - Goto Rollout
>
> **Rollout**
>
> - While size of `foo-next` < `desired-replicas` annotation on `foo-next`
>
>   - increase size of `foo-next`
>   - if size of `foo` > 0 decrease size of `foo`
> - Goto Rename
>
> **Rename**
>
> - delete `foo`
> - create `foo` that is identical to `foo-next`
> - delete `foo-next`
>
> **Abort**
>
> - If `foo-next` doesn't exist
>
>   - Exit and indicate to the user that they may want to simply do a new rollout with the old version
> - If `foo` doesn't exist
>
>   - Exit and indicate not found to the user
> - Otherwise, `foo-next` and `foo` both exist
>
>   - Set `desired-replica`s annotation on `foo` to match the annotation on `foo-next`
>   - Goto Rollout with `foo` and `foo-next` trading places.

Answer (score 0):

There are two fields (`maxSurge` and `maxUnavailable`) on the deployment spec that you can use to control how a rolling update is performed. `kubectl explain deployment.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate` will give you full details about these fields, but in short they determine how many pods you can go over your replica count and how many pods can become unavailable respectively during a rolling update.

For the `maxUnavailable` field to work properly, it's important to configure readiness probes on your pod template properly.

More information can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment#rolling-update-deployment).